# What is the proper way to insert an if statement into a mysql query

Tags: mysql

What is the property way to insert an IF statement into a mysql query?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (column1 > 'value')
```

What if I wanted to put a condition within that query like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ((column1 > 'value')and(IF column2 = 'n' THEN WHERE column3 > '5'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about a [case](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) statement?

Comment: Is it possible to put a IF expression within a WHERE?

Answer (score 2):

Combine your conditions with AND and OR:

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE
     column1 > 'value' AND (column2 <> 'n' OR column3 > '5')
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE (column1 > 'value' and column2 != 'n')
    OR (column1 > 'value' and column2 = 'n' and column3 > '5')
```

Comment: I understand that I could write it this way, but I am try to understand the concept of how if statements are written within a query.